# Using Multiple SSL Certificates on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, elastic-beanstalk

Our multi-tenant app runs on Elastic Beanstalk. Our wildcard cert is on the Beanstalk load balancer (ELB).

For clients that have their own domain name and certificate, we are installing those on new, extra ELB's that connect to the Elastic Beanstalk instance.  This works great until Beanstalk does some autoscaling or something and our extra ELB's get unsubscribed from the instance.

Is there are way to permanently connect extra ELBs to our Elastic Beanstalk instance?  Like adding them to the Auto Scaling Group somehow?

If not, what's the best way to architect this within the confines of Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct answer is to simply add the extra ELBs to your Beanstalk  AutoScaling Group and AWS handles the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to self promote but couldn't find a step-by-step when I was researching this so I figured it out and wrote one. [Adding multiple SSL certificates to an Elastic Beanstalk Application on AWS | Chiedo Labs](https://labs.chiedo.com/blog/adding-multiple-ssl-certificates-to-an-elastic-beanstalk-application-on-aws/)

Comment: Good writeup.  I've been told by AWS technical staff that multiple cert support is coming for ALBs in the next month or so.

Comment: That would be so much easier haha. I'll be on the lookout for that. :)

Comment: We are now writing December 2018 and it's unfortunately still not possible.